# How would I `wget` files and then save them by date downloaded rather than filename?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

My goal: To download 131 JPEGs and save them in a file name format that is relative to the date/time format rather than their file name.

I have already tried things that involve changing the files' names *after* they have already been downloaded. However, these methods do not work because it seems like exif data is not being kept. For example: `jhead -n%Y%m%d-%H%M%S *.jpg` just returns a bunch of errors saying:

```
Possible new names for for '{filename}.jpg' already exist
File '{filename}.jpg' contains no exif date stamp.  Using file date
```

Usually, as in this case, I wind up with less files than I started out with.

So is there some command I can pass to `wget` instead? I have already tried the `--timestamp` option with no success. (The man page is not to clear about what that does.)

Comment: EXIF data is kept *inside the file*. The filesystem has no say on the matter.

Comment: Oh, ok. Perhaps there's no way to solve it, then, unless there's a way to do it without using EXIF data.

Comment: Why not use the files' creation date and a renaming software that sorts by date created.

Comment: As I stated in my question: I tried that.

Comment: @searchfgold6789: Your question states you tried the EXIF timestamp embedded in the photo *(which some websites simply remove to reduce file size, or never add in the first place)*, not the same as timestamps of the file itself.

Comment: @grawity Okay, you are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wget url -O `date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.jpg
```

Don't really know how to change the download URLs, that's something you have to figure out yourself.

Comment: Here's a working example I use
wget http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/planetary-k-index.gif -O /var/www/html/Kindex_images/`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.gif